# How do you get "value" of a selected item in a listview

Tags: vb.net

i use listView in vb.net to display some details (Say, example list of Students in a class).i need to get their student_id , which was the primary key in the student Table

Comment: have you used data binding, or populate listView by code?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using WinForms, as I suspect, when you add an item to the listview, you should set the tag to either the entire DataRow object, or the value of the student_id column.  Then, anywhere that you have a reference to the item, you can access the item's tag property to get the necessary information.  For instance, something like this would work:

```
For Each row As DataRow In table
    Dim item As ListViewItem = ListView1.Items.Add(row("student_name").ToString())
    item.Tag = row(row("student_id").ToString())
Next
```

Then code like this to get the student ID from and item:

```
Private Sub ListView1_ItemSelectionChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItemSelectionChangedEventArgs) Handles ListView1.ItemSelectionChanged
    Dim studentId As String = CType(e.Item.Tag, String)
End Sub
```

Comment: @user27032010 Do you mind accepting this as the best answer, if it is what you were looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Use [ListView.SelectedValue Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listview.selectedvalue.aspx)